# conan user against Jfrog Academy docker Artifactory-CE returns 404

Tags: artifactory, conan

I'm following the Jfrog Academy tutorial. It uses an Artifactory CE in a docker image. I'm at the lesson where you first upload packages to Artifactory.

I added a user and repo and gave the user access to the repo. But when I do

```
conan user -p PASSWORD -r REPO USERNAME
```

I get

```
ERROR: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "File not found."
  } ]
}. [Remote: artifactory]
```

I did check for typos, such as in the user name and password.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is unable to find the remote repository. I tried steps similar to below to configure Conan without any issues.

```
conan remote add <REMOTE> http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/conan/<repository>

conan user -p <API-KEY> -r <REMOTE> <username>
```

If you still have any issues, enable CONAN_LOGGING_LEVEL to debug and see if that helps with additional information on the issue.

Comment: For me the key here is the URL with the extra part of the path.  Don't know where that is documented so if anyone knows that would be helpful.

Comment: Found the documentation here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/use-conan-with-artifactory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using CE instead of OSS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35553410)